# Passing a Vector to Another Vector?

Tags: matlab, vector

What I have:

```
syms X Y
funcF = [ (X.^2 + Y.^2 + X -4), (Y*cos(X) + X*Y.^3 - 1) ]
z0 = [0.5, 2]
```

Say I want to pass `z0` to `funcF`, I'm not sure how to do this. (My knowledge of matlab isn't the greatest)

So I'm currently trying:

```
funcF = funcF(z0)
```

Essentially, I want it to print something like this:

```
[#1   #2]
```

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes.  The OP has clearly show what he/she has tried and where the difficulties are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that expression is symbolic, you need to use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html).  `subs` replaces symbolic variables with whatever you want... and that includes numbers.  Also, because this is a symbolic expression (thanks Nasser), there is no need for point-by-point operators (i.e. `.^`).  You can remove these and use the normal scalar operators.

As such, you want to replace `X` and `Y` in the expression with the corresponding values in `z0`:

```
>> syms X Y;
>> funcF = [ (X^2 + Y^2 + X -4), (Y*cos(X) + X*Y^3 - 1) ];
>> out = subs(funcF, {'X','Y'}, z0)

out =

[ 3/4, 2*cos(1/2) + 3]
```

Comment: the "." is not needed, since these are syms and not numerics. Actually I do not think the "." is even supported for syms as in numerical vectors. It works above because it seems it was just ignored. But it is not needed.

Comment: @Nasser - I simply copied and pasted what the OP put in his/her statement, but you are correct.

Comment: @user2925439 - no worries.  If it works, consider accepting my answer.  This means that you no longer need help in this particular question, and the rest of us can move on to answer other questions.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes everything works great thank you! How do I accept your answer? Don't see it anywhere right now

Comment: @user2925439 - OH! that's easy.  Go to the top of my post, and at the left of it, there's a checkmark icon just underneath the up and down voting arrows.  Click on that.  Thanks and good luck! :)

Comment: @user2925439 - Also make sure you go around your previous questions and accept some of those answers too.  I took a quick look and there are a few questions with some solid answers that helped you out.  Pay it forward and accept their answers too! :).